# How to get HTML source code with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I know... someone already asked this.

But...

When I get the source code from jQuery this way:

```
var html = $("html").html();
```

I get a kind of "processed" source code, not the real one.
I explain:

The html source code ( the real one, typed by me ) is here:

```
<tr>
    <td>POC</td>
    <td>
        Susan Symington - MITRE W150<br/>
        DMSO - <br/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I can see the same code when I ask my browser to show it to me.

When I use jQuery, the same code is:

```
<tr>
    <td>POC</td>
    <td>
        Susan Symington - MITRE W150<br>
        DMSO - <br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Can you see the BR tags? Its important to me that I take the SAME code because I using it in iText PDF conversor. I get some other differences ( div tags positions in different part of code, etc..)

Comment: jquery is extracting the tags/text from the browser's DOM. The dom is by definition fully parsed (and potentially modified) html. it's the internal representation of what the browser THINGS your html is trying to tell it. you can never get back the exact same html.

Comment: Sounds like iText PDF converter needs to learn how to handle `<br>` tags.

Comment: If that's the only problem, replace the `<br>` tags with `<br/>`.

Comment: @undefined some divs are in different positions inside the code. I'll try to replace the tags as you said and post the result. Thanks.

Comment: @j08691 I don't think so. This is a XHTML requirement. http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/FYI-about-xmlworker-and-BR-tags-td4119549.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that I needed to be creative...

I got the page source by using an ajax request ( `$.get` )
Worked like a charm.